# Showing Custom action in process screen

Tags: acumatica

We have created one new action button in Shipments screen and we have configured this button under Actions menu, actually we want to show this action menu in Process Shipments screen also, based on this [How to add an action and handler to the Process Shipments screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106118/how-to-add-an-action-and-handler-to-the-process-shipments-screen) Ruslan post we have achieved this, but we observed that their are two actions buttons appearing under actions menu but with same name after configuring through automation steps. Can some please help me how to solve this. i don't how how to add action menu in process screen using code so i did it through automation steps. Please have a look at below image.
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCrfQ.png)

Comment: Try Restart Application (System > Management > Process > Apply Updates : Restart Application button) or execute iisreset to see if the issue persists or if it's just a glitch.

Comment: Hello HB_Acumatica, sorry for delay in reply, yes we have tried that but no luck.